# define_method in Python

Tags: python, metaprogramming, setattr

I would like to dynamically define some methods for Python class. I googled for a while and found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5449293/1476512). I changed the code a bit to fulfill my requirement.

Here's my codes:

```
class Base(object):

  def add_method(self, field):
    def func(self, value):
      self.colors[field] = value
      return self
    return func

  def define_method(self, *fields):
    for field in fields:
      setattr(self, "with_" + field, self.add_method(field))


class MyColor(Base):

  def __init__(self):
    self.colors = {
      "black": "000",
      "red": "f00",
      "green": "0f0"
    }

    # ========== ==========
    # by doing this, I assume `with_red()` and `with_green()`
    # will be generated, and they're chain-able.
    super(MyColor, self).define_method("red", "green")


s = MyColor()
s.with_red("111").with_green("222")
print(s.colors) 
# should output: {"black": "000", "red": "111", "green": 222}
```

The codes will raise error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 26, in <module>
    s.with_red("111").with_green("222")
TypeError: _with_field() missing 1 required positional argument: 'value'
```

What is wrong?

Thanks for your time!

========== Edit ==========

Sorry, I changed my original implementation on `Base` class, which is as below(has a bug, which always change the last `field` passed to `define_method()`). @Alex's answer stands.

```
class Base:

  def define_method(self, *fields):
    for field in fields:
      def _with_field(self, value):
        self.colors[field] = value
        return self
      setattr(self, "with_" + field, _with_field)
```

Comment: change `setattr(self, "with_" + field, _with_field)` to `setattr(Base, "with_" + field, _with_field)`

Comment: @user1767754, super cool! It works.

Comment: can anyone elaborate a little bit on this `self`, `Base` tihing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What happens is that you set e.g. '**with_red**' attribute on your MyColor instance to a local function defined in Base constructor - note that this is not a class method, just a function, and it takes 2 arguments: '**self**' and '**value**':

```
import inspect
...
s = MyColor()
print(inspect.getargspec(s.with_red))
```

***ArgSpec(args=['self', 'value'], varargs=None, keywords=None, defaults=None)***

An easy fix here would be to make this function take a single argument:

```
def _with_field(value):
   self.colors[field] = value
   return self
```

With this change your code produces the expected output.

Another option is to set '**with_red**' attribute on the class - which makes it a method, then self is passed implicitly and you can keep `_with_field` signature with two arguments.